# Getting Person-Name with id from Worker table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new on sql server and I'm trying to do a little query...

I have 2 tables with this, where W=worker:

Table A: Services

```
Date | Time | Service_Name | ID_W1 | ID_W2 | ID_W3
```

Table B: Workers

```
ID_W | Name | Last Name
```

My question is How do I manage to make a table like this...?

```
Date | Time | Service_Name | ID_W1 | Name_W1 | ID_W2 | Name_W2 | ID_W3 | Name_W3
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: You could join the Workers table multiple times including one more names, W1, W2, W3 for each join.

Comment: This can be answered by here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621624/combine-two-tables-into-one-table

Comment: @ChanjungKim that link works for mysql but this is tagged with sql server. There is no group_concat in sql server. But that isn't what the OP is looking for here. They need a cross tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT s.date, 
       s.time, 
       s.service_name, 
       s.id_w1, 
       w1.NAME AS Name_W1, 
       s.id_w2, 
       w2.NAME AS Name_W1, 
       S.id_w3, 
       w3.NAME AS Name_W1 
FROM   services s 
       INNER JOIN workers w1 
               ON s.id_w1 = w1.id_w 
       INNER JOIN workers w2 
               ON s.id_w2 = w2.id_w 
       INNER JOIN workers w3 
               ON s.id_w3 = w3.id_w
```

Comment: It should be left joins in case a NULL id is set for one of the workers in services.  Otherwise, inner joining on a NULL worker id means the entire row is excluded from the output.

Comment: Depends on the data structure tbh. We can't tell with what the OP has told us.

Comment: This work for me, just replaced inner join with left join because some services just have 1 worker

Comment: Okay - in which case the suggested amend is an improvement!